# Show Only 2 Digits of the Years on the X-Axis of Recharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plot, charts, recharts

In my Recharts plot of data containing date strings, the X-axis looks pretty messy.

[image]

Is it possible to configure Recharts to label the axis with only the last 2 digit of the years? For example, `17`, `18`, `19`, `20` without repeating the label for each year.

```js
import { ResponsiveContainer, LineChart, Line, CartesianGrid, XAxis, YAxis, Tooltip } from 'recharts';


export function Chart() {

    const d = [
        {date: '2017-02-01', price: 231},
        {date: '2017-04-01', price: 453},
        {date: '2017-16-01', price: 123},
        {date: '2018-01-01', price: 234},
        {date: '2018-04-01', price: 958},
        {date: '2018-11-01', price: 163},
        {date: '2019-03-01', price: 293},
        {date: '2019-10-01', price: 471},
        {date: '2020-07-01', price: 881},
        {date: '2020-09-01', price: 122},
    ]

    return (
        <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={400}>
            <LineChart data={d}>
                <Line type="monotone" dataKey="price" stroke="#8884d8" />
                <CartesianGrid stroke="#ccc" strokeDasharray="5 5" />
                <XAxis dataKey="date" />
                <YAxis dataKey="price" />
                <Tooltip />
            </LineChart>
        </ResponsiveContainer>
    )
}
```

---

Additional Problem: Using Bas van der Linden's approach, the resulting chart is really close to what we need! But the data points are not positioned properly along the X-axis.

This become more obvious if we use the `d` array below. In the resulting chart, you can see that the data points in the year 2018 take up much more space on the X axis that the data points in the years 2017, 2019 and 2020 combined. It will be better if the space between the tick labels `17` and `18` are similar in length as the space between the tick labels `18` and `19`.

[image]

```
    const d = [
        { date: "2017-02-01", price: 231 },
        { date: "2017-04-01", price: 453 },
        { date: "2017-16-01", price: 123 }, 

        { date: "2018-01-01", price: 234 },
        { date: "2018-04-01", price: 958 },
        { date: "2018-11-01", price: 163 },
        { date: "2018-11-02", price: 163 },
        { date: "2018-11-03", price: 163 },
        { date: "2018-11-06", price: 163 },
        { date: "2018-11-05", price: 163 },
        { date: "2018-11-07", price: 163 },
        { date: "2018-11-08", price: 163 },
        { date: "2018-11-09", price: 163 },
        { date: "2018-11-00", price: 163 },
        { date: "2018-11-11", price: 163 },
        { date: "2018-11-12", price: 163 },
        { date: "2018-11-13", price: 163 },
        { date: "2018-11-14", price: 163 },
        { date: "2018-11-15", price: 163 },
        { date: "2018-11-16", price: 163 },
        { date: "2018-11-17", price: 163 },

        { date: "2019-03-01", price: 293 },
        { date: "2019-10-01", price: 471 },
        { date: "2020-07-01", price: 881 },
        { date: "2020-09-01", price: 122 }
      ];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
export function Chart() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const d = [
    { date: "2017-02-01", price: 231 },
    { date: "2017-04-01", price: 453 },
    { date: "2017-16-01", price: 123 },
    { date: "2018-01-01", price: 234 },
    { date: "2018-04-01", price: 958 },
    { date: "2018-11-01", price: 163 },
    { date: "2019-03-01", price: 293 },
    { date: "2019-10-01", price: 471 },
    { date: "2020-07-01", price: 881 },
    { date: "2020-09-01", price: 122 },
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    const datesAlreadyListed = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
      const year = d[i].date.split("-")[0].substring(2, 4);
      if (!datesAlreadyListed.includes(year)) {
        datesAlreadyListed.push(year);
        d[i].year = year;
      }
    }
    setData(d);
  }, []);

  return (
    <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={400}>
      <LineChart data={data}>
        <Line type="monotone" dataKey="price" stroke="#8884d8" />
        <CartesianGrid stroke="#ccc" strokeDasharray="5 5" />
        <XAxis dataKey="year" />
        <YAxis dataKey="price" />
        <Tooltip />
      </LineChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
}
```

So the approach above is to add a `year` property to `d` inside a `useEffect` hook. The value of the `year` property is decided based on whether a date has already been encountered while looping through `d`.

If the year value has not been seen before, set the `year` property to this value so it will show up on the y-axis.

---

[Example Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-booth-lkcht?file=/src/App.js:1075-1141)

Comment: Thanks I thinmk your solution is very close to what we one. However, the spacing between the 2 digit year labels on the axis are not spaced properly. Updated the question to provide an example that illustrates this. Wonder if we have a solution that can handle this?